# Древовидное меню jQuery Treeview

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

В общем, есть страницы с этим меню на `jQuery`. 
Почему-то на одной странице все отлично, а на второй при раскрытии меню, оно автоматически и сворачивается.

Вот [страница](http://akvarel.madowl.com.ua/stationery), где работает корректно.
А [вот](http://akvarel.madowl.com.ua/materials), где не корректно.

Если успеть нажать на какую либо категорию из разворачивающегося списка, то отображается нормально на новой странице.
[Вот пример](http://akvarel.madowl.com.ua/materials/35).

В чем причина такого поведения и как это возможно подправить?

Comment: Вот по этому лучше выполнять джс в отдельном файле, а не по коду хтмл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На пункте меню два раза повешено событие `click`.
Т.е. два раза почему-то вызывается `function toggler()`.
Сейчас ищу, в чем причина.

Comment: ты два раза вызываеш $("#tree").treeview(.
прямо перед менюшкой самой и сразу после <!--content-->

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее))) А то я все никак не мог найти баг)))